# Passport facebook authentication not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, facebook-login, passport-facebook

I have a nodeJS application (express), which has a facebook login. I'm using the passport-facebook authentication, described in here [passport-facebook](http://passportjs.org/docs/facebook). My login was still working couple weeks ago ok, but now something has changed. I'm not sure if Facebook has changed something, or if I have. I haven't touched to any of the login code, so I suspect it is something in the facebook's end.

Here is my authentication code:

```
router.get('/', passport.authenticate('facebook'), function(req, res){
});

router.get('/auth/facebook/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook', {
  failureRedirect: '/' }),
  function(req, res) {
  res.redirect('/calendar');
});
```

Basically, I want the app to automatically authenticate the user from the root of the app, and then redirect after the authentication to /calendar.

The symptons are following: If I try to go to the root and I haven't logged in with facebook earlier, then it will take me to the normal facebook login screen, as it should. But then on that screen, there is a warning of:

> Given URL is not permitted by the Application configuration
>   One or more of the given URLs is not permitted by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

I checked all questions related to this, and it seems it is because I haven't configured the app domain and site url properly in the facebook app configuration. But they should be all fine: app domain: localhost, site url: http://localhost:3000/

So I don't know why it is complaining about it? I do not have any subdomains. The only routes I do have are: (/, /calendar, /calendar/events). The last /calendar/events routes are ajax routes. Anyways, after I enter my facebook credentials and login, then the page will redirect me to a empty page, with url: (https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1). I opened the developer's tools, and I see one error message in its console:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

But, now I am actually logged in. Because if I now go to root or to /calendar, it will take me to correct page and show I'm logged in properly. So apparently the log in works, but there are some issues with redirection and allowed URL's. I just don't seem to know what and why. I'm using mongodDB as database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be because of what site you have registered in your app.  If you have registered it to http://localhost:3000/ you should work with domain localhost that for the callback.  And if you have registered it as http://127.0.0.1:3000/ then you should work with 127...

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why this even worked, but I found a solution. Previously, I had configured valid OAuth redirect URI to be http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/facebook/callback, and it was working all good. Now I changed it to use localhost instead of 127.0.0.1:3000, and that seemed to do the trick. Now everything is working as expected, though I don't know why. If someone is able to clearly tell me why, I will mark that as the correct answer.