# Accessing GET routes inside React App on Express Server in production

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, passport.js

Have followed along with one of Stephen Girder's videos on Udemy and wanted to implement some FaceBook login flow to my own app.

But I can't seem to access the app.get routes in production mode. Everything works fine on localhost and development. When I go to /auth/facebook all I get is a blank screen.

I am using react-router-dom. I am trying various techniques such as socket.io but just can't seem to get it working :(

Server index.js file

```
/* global __dirname process env */
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const express = require('express');
const cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
const keys = require('./server/config/keys');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const auth = require('./server/routes/auth');
const passport = require('passport');
const https = require('https');
const cors = require('cors')
const socketio = require('socket.io')
const authRouter = require('./server/lib/auth.router')
const passportInit = require('./server/lib/passport.init')
const { SESSION_SECRET, CLIENT_ORIGIN } = require('./config')
const fs = require('fs');
const pug = require('pug');
const path = require('path');
const gulp = require('gulp');

let server;

mongoose
    .connect(keys.mongoURI)
    .then(() => console.log('connection successful'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

require('./server/models/SimpleTask');
require('./server/models/simpleLongTask');
require('./server/models/DailyJournals');
require('./server/models/Tracks');
require('./server/models/Hats');
require('./server/models/DailyTaskList');
require('./server/models/RepeatTask');
require('./server/models/RedueTask');
require('./server/models/TrackTree');

// used for development purposes.
const morgan = require('morgan');
const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('./server/keys/server.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./server/keys/server.crt'),
};

const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
// If we are in production we are already running in https
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  server = http.createServer(app)
}
// We are not in production so load up our certificates to be able to
// run the server in https mode locally
else {
  const certOptions = {
        key: fs.readFileSync('./server/keys/server.key'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('./server/keys/server.crt')
  }
  server = https.createServer(certOptions, app)
}
app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(
    cookieSession({
        maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
        keys: 'dashgkjlahgfkljashfkjasdflkhasdfjklh'
    })
);
app.use(cors({
  origin: CLIENT_ORIGIN
}))
const io = socketio(server)
app.set('io', io)

// app.use(localJWT.initialize());
require('./server/routes/book')(app);
require('./server/routes/auth')(app, passport);
require('./server/routes/loginRoutes')(app, passport);
require('./server/routes/tasksRoutes')(app);
require('./server/routes/calendarRoutes')(app);
require('./server/routes/trackRoutes')(app);
// require('./server/routes/frontEnd')(app);


if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    // Express will serve up production assets.
    // Like our main.js file, or main.css file
    app.use(express.static('client/build'));
    // Express will serve up the index.html file if it doesn't know the route....
    const path = require('path');
    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
    });
}
//
// // reload code
// app.use(express.static('./dist/', {
//     extensions: ['html', 'htm']
// }));

app.get('/wake-up', (req, res) => res.send(''))
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, () => {
  console.log('listening...')
})
```

Login Routes.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passport = require('passport');
const express = require('express');

const User = require('../models/User');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const settings = require('../config/settings');
require('../services/facebookPassport')(passport);

module.exports = (app, passport) => {
    // send to facebook to do the authentication
    app.get(
        '/auth/facebook',
        passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope: 'email' })
    );
    app.get(
        '/auth/facebook/callback',
        passport.authenticate('facebook', {
            session: false
        }), (req, res) => {
            const token = jwt.sign(req.user.toJSON(), settings.secret);
            res.cookie('jwtToken', token);
            res.redirect('/social_auth');
        }
    );
    app.post(
        '/connect/local',
        passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
            successRedirect: '/profile', // redirect to the secure profile section
            failureRedirect: '/connect/local', // redirect back to the signup page
            failureFlash: true // allow flash messages
        })
    );
    // facebook ------- authorization.
    app.get(
        '/connect/facebook',
        passport.authorize('facebook', {
            scope: ['public_profile', 'email']
        })
    );
    // handle the callback after facebook has authorized the user
    app.get(
        '/connect/facebook/callback',
        passport.authorize('facebook', {
            successRedirect: '/profile',
            failureRedirect: '/'
        })
    );
    // route middlewarer to ensure user is logged in before authorization
    function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
        if (req.isAuthenticated()) return next();
        res.redirect('/');
    }
};
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console (client side) that indicate an issue?

Comment: Nope, https://www.produktivv.com/auth/facebook - just shows React is loaded. Using heroku cli to deploy also.

Comment: Getting 302 status error on Heroku....

Comment: You might want to do a quick check on your configuration: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30681342/passport-facebook-authentication-not-working I received a "not logged in error" from the page (via facebook).